# Showing Drawing lines with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, drawing

im trying to get the line drawing to show on first click. So you are able to see where the line will end on second click. At the moment you cant see the line until you click a second point but i cant work out what im missing so that the line shows up on the first click and it carries on displaying until the second click.

```js
$(function() {
  var x1 = null,
    y1 = null;
  var offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0;

  function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#demo')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });

    return line;
  }

  $('#demo').click(function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

      if (x1 == null) {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
      } else {
        createLine(x1, y1, x, y);
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    .delegate('.line', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      x1 = y1 = null;
      return false;
    });





});
```

```css
div.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000;
  /* Black fill */
}

#demo {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}

div.transforming-on-corner {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> click two point to draw a line :</h3>
<div id="demo" class="wide">

</div>
```

Comment: You could use canvas element for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is draw a unique line on the `$('#demo').mousemove` event after your first click. On each move remove that line by referencing its id (ex: `#moveLine`) and draw the new one at your mouse position. Once you click to draw a new line it will clear the `id` of the old line so it becomes permanent.

```js
$(function() {
  var x1 = null,
    y1 = null;
  var offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0;
  
  var moveLineId = "moveLine";

  function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {

    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#demo')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });

    if(id != null) line.attr('id', id);

    return line;
  }

  $('#demo').click(function(event) {
      $(".line").removeAttr('id');
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

      if (x1 == null) {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    .delegate('.line', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      x1 = y1 = null;
      return false;
    });
    

  $('#demo').mousemove(function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;
        
      
      
      if (x1 != null) {
        $("#" + moveLineId).remove();
        createLine(x1, y1, x, y, moveLineId)
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    
});
```

```css
div.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000;
  /* Black fill */
}

#demo {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}

div.transforming-on-corner {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> click two point to draw a line :</h3>
<div id="demo" class="wide">

</div>
```

Comment: Wow awesome. That is what i was trying to achieve. thank you

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to always work when you are trying to stop the line from drawing on the second click. (Sometimes i have to click up to 5 times and a error appears)